# ExtJs Form Rendering not happening at all

Tags: html, extjs4.1

I am trying to create a Form using ExtJS . The files are placed properly but no rendering is happening :

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ext</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="aa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.getElementById('aa'),
    title: 'User Form',
    height: 130,
    width: 280,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstName'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastName'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
            name: 'birthDate'
        }
    ]
});
```

Anybody any idea what am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app.js, try running that code when the onReady event has been fired e.g.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.getElementById('aa'),
        title: 'User Form',
        height: 130,
        width: 280,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
            {
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                name: 'firstName'
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                name: 'lastName'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
                name: 'birthDate'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Grant, I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Ext.onReady()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-onReady):

> Adds a function to be called when the DOM is ready, and all required
>   classes have been loaded.
>
> If the DOM is ready and all classes are loaded, the passed function is
>   executed immediately.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld5e6/

Comment: THanks a lot CD . Got it , was not firing  onReady()